# Not able to load static files

Tags: python, django, static

I tried fetching static files for my website but nothing seems to work even the other stackoverflow answers.
please help on this.

settings.py -

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static','static_root')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static','static_dirs')
]
```

File is present in :
parent_folder>static>static_dirs>css>cover.css

*HTML*

```
<html lang="en">
{% load staticfiles %}
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="Aman Turate">
<title>Aman Turate - Resume</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/cover.css' %}">
```

Comment: which Django version are you using?

Comment: @Giordano its 2.1.4...

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Update your settings.py to this

```
.........
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
.........
```

Make sure the static folder is in the root (i.e where manage.py is)

Comment: thanks for help.... but its not working... did u keep files directly inside static folder?

Comment: From the code you posted you need to add the asset folder in the static folder. 

static>css>cover.css

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to consider here and I am not sure which applies because I'm working on pure assumptions of your situation without knowing:

1. What is `BASE_DIR` set to
2. Have you run `manage.py collectstatic`
3. what is your server setup or are you just working off the django development server?
4. Where are the files you're trying to link to actually placed

Anyway here is some info I hope will be useful. I will break down how the settings files relates to your template file and hopefully that will help you debug your problem.

`STATIC_URL = '/static/'` -- > the value of this is what will be appended to the static file you are linking in your template. It is the relative url after your domain name. So `{% static 'css/styles.css' %}` will be rendered as `/static/css/styles.css` in your html page when it is loaded.

`STATIC_ROOT`  is the absolute path of where your files are located on disk. It tells django where to place all static files collected from your apps when you run `manage.py collectstatic` [see here for details.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT)

`STATICFILES_DIRS` tells django where to find project static files. By default Django will look for a `static` directory in each registered app and collect the files in there and place then in your `STATIC_ROOT` folder. If you want to put static files in a different directory in your project and you want django to know about it then you list those paths in this config variable.

With your code:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static','static_root')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static','static_dirs')
]
```

`{% static 'css/cover.css' %}` is translating to `/static/css/cover.css`, your telling django the root directory to collect static files is `<your BASE_DIR>/static/static_root` so here you can see that there might be a miss match in locations. Again I don't know if you ran `collectstatic`. your `STATICFILES_DIR` is just going to look for static files in `<your BASE_DIR>/static/static_root` to then put them in `<your BASE_DIR>/static/static_root` ... if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. I have deployed my personal site to [http://amanturate.pythonanywhere.com]. I did run 'collectstatic' on my virtualenv and files are present in static_root. I am assuming BASE_DIR means the DIR where manage.py is present. I am getting `PAGE NOT FOUND Request Method: GET Request URL: http://amanturate.pythonanywhere.com/static/admin/css/base.css`

Comment: As I have explained, you've told django to place your files in `<your BASE_DIR>/static/static_root/admin/css/base.css`. You've told the browser to look for files in `/static/admin/css/base.css`. Check your directory tree and where files are actually located.

Also no idea what server pythonanywhere uses, does it have its own server settings, is it using apache or nginx or something else? Have you configured that where needed?